# How do I refactor this into `withAuth` using HOC? Or is it possible to use hooks here in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, higher-order-components

```
import { useSession } from 'next-auth/react'

import { LoginPage } from '@/client/components/index'

const Homepage = () => {
  const session = useSession()

  if (session && session.data) {
    return (
      <>
        <div>Homepage</div>
      </>
    )
  }
  return <LoginPage />
}

export default Homepage
```

Basically, I don't want to write the same boilerplate of `Login` & `useSession()` on every page.

I want something like:

```
import { withAuth } from '@/client/components/index'

const Homepage = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div>Homepage</div>
    </>
  )
}

export default withAuth(Homepage)
```

Or if possible `withAuthHook`?

I currently have done the following:

```
import React from 'react'
import { useSession } from 'next-auth/react'

import { LoginPage } from '@/client/components/index'

export const withAuth = (Component: React.Component) => (props) => {
    const AuthenticatedComponent = () => {
        const session = useSession()
        if (session && session.data) {
            return <Component {...props} />
        }
        return <LoginPage />
    }

    return AuthenticatedComponent
}
```

But I get an error:

> JSX element type 'Component' does not have any construct or call signatures.ts(2604)

If I use `React.ComponentType` as mentioned in the answer below, I get an error saying:

> TypeError: (0 , *client_components_index__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0*_.withAuth) is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was [hidden in the docs](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#custom-client-session-handling). I had to specify the following `Auth` function in `_app.tsx`:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { AppProps } from 'next/app'
import { SessionProvider, signIn, useSession } from 'next-auth/react'
import { Provider } from 'urql'

import { client } from '@/client/graphql/client'

import '@/client/styles/index.css'

function Auth({ children }: { children: any }) {
    const { data: session, status } = useSession()
    const isUser = !!session?.user
    
    useEffect(() => {
        if (status === 'loading') return
        if (!isUser) signIn()
    }, [isUser, status])

    if (isUser) {
        return children
    }

    return <div>Loading...</div>
}

interface AppPropsWithAuth extends AppProps {
    Component: AppProps['Component'] & { auth: boolean }
}

const CustomApp = ({ Component, pageProps: { session, ...pageProps } }: AppPropsWithAuth) => {
    return (
        <SessionProvider session={session}>
            <Provider value={client}>
                {Component.auth ? (
                    <Auth>
                        <Component {...pageProps} />
                    </Auth>
                ) : (
                    <Component {...pageProps} />
                )}
            </Provider>
        </SessionProvider>
    )
}

export default CustomApp
```

And on my actual page, I had to specify `Component.auth` as `true`:

```
const Homepage = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div>Homepage</div>
    </>
  )
}

Homepage.auth = true
export default Homepage
```

A nice summary of what it does can be found on https://simplernerd.com/next-auth-global-session

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
export const withAuth = (Component: React.ComponentType) => (props) => {
...
```

https://flow.org/en/docs/react/types/#toc-react-componenttype

Edit:
Try like this:

```
export const withAuth = (Component: React.ComponentType) => (props) => {
    const session = useSession()
    if (session && session.data) {
        return <Component {...props} />
    }
    return <LoginPage />
}

return AuthenticatedComponent
```

}

Comment: i think i spoke too soon. that did work but i get `withAuth` is not a function error :(

Comment: @deadcoder0904 I think it's because `AuthenticatedComponent` is declared as functional component, but what you return from `withAuth` is already a component (function). What you should return is just the JSX, not the function `AuthenticatedComponent`.

Comment: oh makes sense now! but don't know how do i do that from hoc? i tried calling it like `AuthenticatedComponent()` but nope that doesn't work.

Comment: @deadcoder0904 I added some example code.

Comment: i did that only but it was giving an error but no worries, found the solution. it was hidden in the docs (needs more appropriate naming). i'll post it as an answer :)